# I'm trying to add and item to cart, and also delete it through the clear cart button

Tags: reactjs, shopping-cart

I'm trying to add an item to the cart, and also delete it through the clear cart button. I hope I have pasted the necessary code correctly. Had tried to work on it but after a few failing tests, reverted the code to the original. I'm still new to react I hope you understand.

```
function Home() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      // auto-login
      fetch("/coffees").then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          res.json().then((data) => setData(data))
        }
      });
    }, [])
    console.log(data)
    return (
    <>
    <div className="box">
        <div className="projo">
        <h2 >Welcome to Coffee-cafe</h2>
        </div>
            <div className="projects">
             {data.map((data) =>{
              return(
                <div className="card">
                    <img className="avatar" src={data.coffee_image} alt="coffee"></img>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <h4><b>{data.coffee_name}</b></h4>
                        <p id="desc">{data.description}</p>
                        <p className="price">{data.price}</p>
                        {/* <p>{data.category}</p> */}
                        <button onClick={() => ({})} className="btn1" id="btn1">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>    
    </div>

    </>

       
    )
}

export default Home;

function Checkout() {
    return (
        <>
         <div className="section">
       <div className="photo">
           <img className="dp" src={image1} alt="coffee"></img>
           <div className="info">
               <h3>Coffee:</h3>
               <p>Price:</p>
               <p>Category:</p>
               <div className="check-out-btn">
                   {/* <button className="add">AddToCart</button> */}
                   <button className="delete">ClearCart</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where do you store your cart items?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you mean the items i'm fetching from the database?

Comment: You need to store the items added to the cart as state

Comment: ow, don't think I have done that already